# Displaying errors in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display errors in laravel after validation but i just get a blank screen instead of errors being displayed on screen.

Controller

```
   $this->validate($request, [
            'ObservationNotes'=>'required',
        'ImageUpload.*'=>'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg |max:2048'
    ]);
```

I have got the following to display the errors but still nothing, I get errors on other pages its just this one page that it doesn't apply to.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    There was a problem with your input.<br><br>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: If other sites are working the problem is may related to another source. Are you sure that you dont get redirected?

Comment: The errors might no be flashing to the session, you're being redirect to the correct page?

Comment: No there is no redirect, its loading the same page just blank with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$request->all()` or `$request->json()->all()` to see if it works.

```
$this->validate($request->all(), [
        'ObservationNotes'=>'required',
    'ImageUpload.*'=>'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg |max:2048'
]);
```

Or use

```
$request->validate([
        'ObservationNotes'=>'required',
    'ImageUpload.*'=>'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg |max:2048'
]);
```

Comment: Hey, tried this and it doesn't work. Today i tried adding the image upload to the previous page and validated it before and and it works perfectly fine its just on this page.